# I'm facing a problem in Blender after trying to use Archimesh

Tags: python, error, archimesh-add-on

I'm facing this problem in Blender and I don't know how to solve it.

```
"Python Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\3.3\scripts\startup\bl_operators\wm.py", line 2109, in execute owner_id = workspace.owner_ids[self.owner_id]

KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "archimesh" not found'
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't said exactly what you're doing to create the error and it's impossible to see from your image. In any case you should report it as a bug via Help > Report a Bug  as you're using a recently released version of Blender.

Comment: I added Archimesh to the Quick Favorites and clicked "Q" to use. That's how the error is happening.

Comment: In that case you should definitely report it as a bug.

Comment: Have you checked that archimesh is enabled in *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*? If it isn't and you've manually added the shortcut, this might be the cause.